# Template specialization depending on a unknown typedef

Tags: c++, templates

In C++ I want to specialize a templated function. So far so good.
The problem is that the type that specialize my template depends on a typedef to which I don't have access.

## Purpose explication

The user must first define a typedef for the class `Surface_mesh` by specifying some types in the template.

```cpp
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>::Point_3> Mesh;
```

`Mesh` may vary according to the user's needs, but it will always have the following typedef:

- Mesh::Face_index
- Mesh::Vertex_index
- Mesh::Edge_index

Now I want to write a function that has a different implementation depending on `Face_index`, `Vertex_index` or `Edge_index` but not depending on the typedef `Mesh`.
Here's how the user could use it:

```cpp
std::cout << foo<void>() << std::endl;
std::cout << foo<Mesh::Face_index>() << std::endl;
std::cout << foo<Mesh::Vertex_index>() << std::endl;
std::cout << foo<Mesh::Edge_index>() << std::endl;

>> "Default foo() called"
>> "foo() for Face_index called"
>> "foo() for Vertex_index called"
>> "foo() for Edge_index called"
```

## What I have tried

This first implementation work if `foo` had access to the `Mesh` tyedef, but this is not the case:

```cpp
template <typename EI> //for Element Index
std::string foo(void)
{
    return "Default foo() called";
}

template <>
std::string foo<Mesh::Face_index>(void)
{
    return "foo() for Face_index called";
}

...
```

So I have tried something like that, but it doesn't work:

```cpp
template <typename SM, typename EI> //for Surface Mesh and Element Index
std::string foo(void)
{
    return "Default foo() called";
}

template <typename SM>
std::string foo<SM::Face_index>(void)
{
    return "foo() for Face_index called";
}

...
```

## Question

Do you know if it is possible to do what I want, and if so how to do it or do you have links to sites with explanations that could help me?

---

## EDIT

Here is a simplified implementation of Surface_Mesh:

```cpp
namespace CGAL
{
    // Implementation for Surface_mesh::Vertex_index
    class SM_Vertex_index
    {
        //...
    };

    // Implementation of Surfae_mesh::Face_index
    class SM_Face_index
    {
        //...
    };

    template <typename P>
    class Surface_mesh
    {
    public:
        typedef SM_Vertex_index Vertex_index;
        typedef SM_Face_index Face_index;
        //... (P is used in the code)
    };
}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if `Mesh::Vertex_index` and `Mesh::Face_index` are the same type?

Comment: What are the types of the index typedefs? Also, let's say that `Face_index = int`. Do you only care about the fact that it's `int` or the fact that it corresponds to `Face_index`?

Comment: Looks like you try partially specialize template. Partial specialization of functions templates is not allowed. You have to define class which will be partially specialized then use it in a function. Anyway to help you fix it we need [mcve], since I'm not fully understand your problem.

Comment: @super Face_index is a typedef for the class `SM_Face_index`, (same for other xxx_index) so for example `Mesh::Vertex_index` will never be the same as `Mesh::Face_index`. In your example, I only car about the fact that `Face_index = int` and not the fact that it corresponds to `Face_index`

Comment: @n314159  `Vertex_index`  and `Face_index` are typedef to redefine different class. So they never will be the same.

Comment: @CharrièreMaxime So can you make a specialization for `SM_Face_index` then? If not, why?

Comment: @super the documentation does not really give a guarantee about that. The documentation claims, that `Vertex_index` is actually defined within `Mesh` and does not expose `SM_Face_index`, so this relies on the OP making use of internal not documented knowledge of the API. It indeed would work but has the risk that it could break with any update of CGAL.

Comment: @t.niese Sounds like information that should be included in the question. Am I supposed to guess what documentation we are talking about? Am I even supposed to have to go look through some documentation to understand the question?

Comment: @super Nice, it worked with your solution ! I was writing a minimal reproductible example for a better understanding, but making a specialization for `SM_Face_index` and not `Mesh::Face_index` was what I wanted to do. Tks !
Sorry for the poor clarity of the question.

Comment: @CharrièreMaxime I initially wrote this as an answer. But I don't really suggest it because it uses internal not documented information.

Comment: @CharrièreMaxime will it really be used like `foo<Mesh::Face_index>()` (with no parameter passed)  or will you actually pass a `Face_index` as a parameter into the function?

Comment: @t.niese No, foo will not have parameter. Otherwise I could have overloaded foo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CGAL `Face_index` is - except for the case when the documentation is created - just a `typedef` for `SM_Face_idex` (`typedef SM_Face_index Face_index;`) and the same for all surface meshes.

So theoretically you could just do:

```
template <typename T>
std::string foo(void)
{
    return "Default foo() called";
}

template <>
std::string foo<SM_Face_index>(void)
{
    return "foo() for Face_index called";
}
```

This would work for the current CGAL versions, but I don't see anything in the documentation, that this will be guaranteed to be that way in the future.

The problem is that the documentation claims that `Face_index` is an actual class defined within Mesh and not that it is a `typedef` of a type independent of the surface mesh.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to get your mind, but I think the follow code may help you. It works in vs 2017.

```
// cls && cl x.cpp /EHsc && x

#include <iostream>

template<typename P, typename V, typename D> class ObjA
{
public:
    typedef P POSI;
    typedef V VERT;
    D extra;
};

typedef ObjA<int, double, float> Mesh;

template<typename T> void foo() noexcept
{
    std::cout << __FUNCSIG__ << "\n";
}

void foo() noexcept
{
    std::cout << __FUNCSIG__ << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    foo<Mesh::POSI>(); // void __cdecl foo<int>(void) noexcept
    foo<Mesh::VERT>(); // void __cdecl foo<double>(void) noexcept
    foo(); // void __cdecl foo(void) noexcept 
    return 0;
}
```